# Different methods of extracting a subset from a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to understand the data.table way of doing things. I have tried to list some different methods of extracting a subset from  a data.table. My intention is to learn the syntax.

```
DT <- data.table(x1=c("b","c", "a", "b", "a", "b"), x2a=as.character(1:6),m1=seq(10,60,by=10),m2=1:6)

#### Method 1
DT[x1 == 'a'& x2a == '3',1:3, with=FALSE]
   x1 x2a m1
1:  a   3 30

#### Method 2
subset(DT,x1 == 'a' & x2a == '3',select = 1:3)
   x1 x2a m1
1:  a   3 30

#### Method 3
setkey(DT,x1,x2a)
DT[.('a','3')]
   x1 x2a m1 m2
1:  a   3 30  3

#### Method 4 - No keys set
DT[,.(x1='a',x2a='3')] # how do I get all the columns?
   x1 x2a
1:  a   3
DT[,.(x1='a',x2a='3'),.SD,.SDcols=1:3] #error message
DT[,.(x1='a',x2a='3'),lapply(.SD),.SDcols=1:3] # what function should I give just to get the rows?
Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default

#### Method 5 - No keys set
DT[.('a','3'),by=.(x1,x2a)] # Should this not be the same as key setting?
DT[.('a','3'),by=.('x1','x2a')] # Should there be quotes on x1 and x2a? When?
DT[.('a','3'),keyby=.('x1','x2a')] # When and where should keyby be used? Nice to see an example
```

Methods 1 to 3 work fine. But I would like to have help with methods 4 and 5.

I want the same results from methods 4 and 5, as from 1 to 3. How do I use method 4 and use .SD & .SDcols?

Comment: Please be more specific regarding the expected results.

Comment: If you want to learn the syntax, read the [getting started guides on github](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started)

Comment: Method 4 doesn't make sense. You are just assigning new values to new variables. `=` is like `<-` (in most cases), try it with `DT[,.(x1='gdgdfg',x2a='564564')]`. Instead of Method 4 just use Method 1 as in `DT[x1 == 'a'& x2a == '3']`. Regarding Method 5, `by` isn't setting a key rather just used for aggregation. You will use `keyby` when you want your aggregation result sorted. compare `DT[, sum(m2), by = x1]` with `DT[, sum(m2), keyby = x1]`.

Comment: Though `keyby` also sets a key, so you could do something like `DT[, sum(m2), keyby = x1]["b"]` too.

Comment: @Roland I have stated what my expected results. I am interested to know how to use .SD and .SDcols for my specific case. I agree that it is a contrived one.

Comment: @David Arenburg +1 Thanks for showing an example of using keyby.

Comment: @Jaap I have tried to read the guides. Seems like I require extra help.

Comment: @CathG  I have added line breaks. Please let me know if this suffices.

Comment: thanks it's less compact like that :-) I wouldn't mind some spaces after the commas (eg) ;-)